# Build of PCL lib fails with new VS2019 agent?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, azure-devops, portable-class-library

If I switch my AzureDevOps CI lane from a `Hosted VS2017` agent to a `Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019` agent, the build breaks with:

```
##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Windows, macOS, or Linux.
Version      : 2.140.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: . 'd:\a\1\s\build.ps1'
##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'd:\a\_temp\23906d3e-3711-4e1b-8106-8a59074e5e3c.ps1'"
Preparing to run build script...
Running build script...
Could not load D:\a\1\s\tools\Addins\Cake.SemVer.3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Cake.SemVer.dll (missing Semver, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null))

========================================
libs
========================================
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.0.360.33175' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
##[error]Cake.exe : D:\a\1\s\Source\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\zxing.portable.csproj(341,11): error MSB4226: The imported project 
##[error]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Also, tried to 
find "Microsoft\Portable\v4.5\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for 

##[error]$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files 

##[error](x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the 

##[error]<Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.

##[error]At D:\a\1\s\build.ps1:233 char:1

##[error]+ &$CAKE_EXE $cakeArguments

##[error]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (D:\a\1\s\Source...e search paths.:String) [], RemoteException

##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

##[error] 

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

The CI is trying to build the `dev` branch of [this opensource project from github](https://github.com/redth/zxing.net.mobile).

Does this mean VS2019 doesn't support building PCL projects now? Any suggestion for a fix?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean VS2019 doesn't support building PCL projects now? Any suggestion for a fix?

According to the document [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-upgrade-visual-studio-projects-2019?view=vs-2017#project-types):

[image]

So, Visual Studio 2019 still support building PCL projects.

The reason for this issue is that the Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019 agent not install the component `.NET Portable Library targeting pack` by default:

[image]

You can check the [Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md#visual-studio-2019-enterprise) for some more details.

To resolve this issue, you could create your private agent and install that component.

Hope this helps.